# Android Studio Build fails with no useful error message

Tags: android-studio

I have an existing Java plus C (i.e. NDK) Android app. The build fails on my new Mac M1, with no useful error information. I can't tell if this is due to some M1 specific issue, or because I have installed the latest Android Studio, NDK and friends, or what.

I tried creating a new, minimal Java + NDK app using Android Studio, and it worked. I compared build.gradle files, bringing the old ones into concordance with the new as much as is possible. That does not help.

I am hoping someone can help me find out why it is failing, with no error message, or suggest a way to get this working.

The build fails at Gradle task:

`Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`

The only error message is in the event log:

`3:15 PM  Gradle build failed with 1 error(s) in 9 s 154 ms`

Files below:

**Build Log**

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /Volumes/SSD1/PERM/tvs/android-intellij/projects/Radar_Main

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
```

**Top Level build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3" //port
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tinyvital.wxr"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29  

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }   
        }   

    }   
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }   
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }   
    }   
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2" //port
        }   
    }   
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    implementation "ch.acra:acra-http:5.3.0"
    implementation "ch.acra:acra-toast:5.3.0"
    implementation "ch.acra:acra-limiter:5.3.0"

    def acraVersion = '5.7.0'
    implementation "ch.acra:acra-http:$acraVersion"
    implementation "ch.acra:acra-toast:$acraVersion"
    implementation "ch.acra:acra-limiter:$acraVersion"

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}
```

Comment: Just a Wild guess, I tried to compile my project with a different ndk then what I used and I would get errors. Keeping the same ndk for my project helped me but this is a temporary solution

Comment: Hi - I did try that. I found that the JDK of the IDE was crashing - with a classic dump - processor registers, list of threads, etc.

Comment: I see so did you solve your issue?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: No - haven't found a solution. So far, I am unable to develop my app on the M1 Mac. I am having to use an older Intel Mac to do it.

I have no idea if anyone else is having this, or how to communicate with Google about it. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: I solved a similar issue by switching to a different JDK per https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk

Comment: With then current version of Android Studio and NDK, I am able to build on the M1 processor. Finally!

I think the NDK is tricky, open source stuff plus proprietary, not adequately portable C++ or something like that.

But at least it worked for me, and my app is large - >50,000 lines of Java and >16000 of C.